# How to solve this percentage question?

Tags: percentages

The Price of A is twice that of another fan B. The price of A is increased by 10% and that of B is decreased by 20%. Find the percentage decrease in the sum of the prices of the fans.

I am fighting myself to solve this one.

Comment: $2B\times1.10+B\times0.80=2B+B$, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=2b$ suppose $a=\$200;\;b=\$100$ sum is $\$300$

$a\to a+10\%\,a=\$220$

$b\to b-20\%\,b=\$80$

The sum is $\$300$ and is unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Set the price of fan B to $x$. The price of fan A is $2x$. The sum of those prices is $3x$. Now the prices change: the new price of A is $2x * 1.1 = 2.2x$. The new price of B is $x * 0.8 = 0.8x$. The sum of those new prices is $2.2x + 0.8x = 3x$, so the price of the sum doesn't change, so the percentage decrease in sum of the prices of the fans is $0\%$.